# What security requirements should implement a L2L VPN in order to protect one end from the other?

Tags: vpn

I would like to create a L2L VPN between two organizations. Due to the hyphotesis that WannaCry was propagated in great part using these kind of connections, I would like to implement security measures to protect one end from the other.

What security requirements should be implemented?

**Edit:** From NIST "Guide to IPsec VPNs" a gateway-to-gateway or L2L VPN "is done tipically by deploying a VPN gateway onto each network and establishing a VPN connection between the two gateways. Traffic between the two networks that needs to be secured passes within the established VPN connection between the two VPN gateways. The VPN gateway may be a dedicated device that only performs VPN functions, or it may be part of another network device, such as a firewall or router."

Comment: You're the only user of the [tag:l2l] tag, and that ag is undefined. So, I kind of think you **must** define what L2L means, even if it's a common term in your business.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It means LAN-to-LAN. https://superuser.com/questions/936062/expanding-wireless-coverage-what-are-the-differences-between-lan-to-lan-and-lan

Answer (score 1):

Some security measure I have gathered:

- The remote site should have connectivity only to what is needed (internal IP ranges should be restricted).
- The remote site should have connectivity only to the ports and services that are needed.
- Only authorized remote sites should be able to connect.
- There should be an Intrusion Prevention System (IPS) between the remote site and us.
- Communications should be encrypted.
- Communications should be allowed to initiate only from the remote site to us, not the other way.

Comment: *Communications should be allowed to initiate only from the remote site to us, not the other way*  If your intention is to protect your network from threats coming from the other network through the L2L VPN,  I think you should only allow communtication to initiate from your organization towards the other end.